# Can I write an alias that takes an argument?

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, alias, g++

I have some remote machines, where I need to compile some source code.
What I normally do is write an alias, that says something like:

```
alias g++='g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv`'
```

Then when I go to compile remotely, I would do `g++ -o test test.cpp`.

For whatever reason, Ubuntu wont let me do that. Instead, Ubuntu works, when I do:

```
g++ file.cpp -o file `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv`
```

But this means I cannot write an alias for g++. Is there a way I can write an alias that will take an argument? what should I do?

Comment: works on debian, and raspbian.

Comment: Shell aliases are essentially just simple text substitution macros - if you want to do anything more complex (such as control the position of additional arguments) you would need to use a *shell function*. However in this case, IMNSHO you'd be much better advised to create a simple `Makefile` or even to define appropriate shell *variables* such as `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`

Comment: Some thing like `alias blah='function _blah(){ echo "First: $1"; echo "Second: $2"; };_blah'` would be it.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: *Use `command g++` in a shell function instead of `g++` in an alias.*

As [6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) says:

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as
>   in `csh`. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used
>   (see [Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions)).

Although an alias will expand even when it appears in front of additional text, aliases do not themselves support [positional parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) (i.e., command-line [arguments](http://foldoc.org/argument)), so you cannot use an alias to carry out your present task. That is, you cannot use an alias to run a command with user-specified arguments *followed by* additional arguments.

As you've found, you can use an alias to make `g++ file.cpp -o file` run:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv` file.cpp -o file
```

But *not* to make `g++ file.cpp -o file` run this command:

```
g++ file.cpp -o file `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv`
```

So, if you want that, you will probably want to use a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions):

```bash
g++ () {
    command g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv` "$@"
}
```

You can:

- Run that on the command-line, and it will be defined as long as the current shell is running, within that shell instance only, *or*
- add it to your `~/.bashrc` file, and start a new shell or run `. ~/.bashrc`.

This defines function called `g++`. Since, unlike aliases, functions can call themselves, I've used the `command` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) to prevent undesired [recursion](http://foldoc.org/recursion). `command g++` calls the external `g++` command. [`"$@"` expands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) to all the command-line arguments passed to the function.

In the very rare case that `g++` really *needed* to be an alias, you could "cheat" and define it as an alias to a function (just as you may define an alias to any other command). You could do that either by defining the function first or by defining it each time in the alias (as [George suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876933/can-i-write-an-alias-that-takes-an-argument#comment1363447_876933)). However, there is no need for you to do this; a function will work fine.

Of course, you might not *always* want `g++` to have the output of `pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv` passed to it. So you might want to put the alias definition in a file and source it only when you want it. If your definition is in `g++-fn.sh` in your home directory, then to enable the function you can run:

```
. ~/g++-fn.sh
```

And to disable the function (no matter how it was defined), you can run:

```
unset -f g++
```

I should add that, for anything but tiny or otherwise trivial programs, you should at least consider using `make` (instead of invoking `g++` yourself with the output of `pkg-config` each time), as [steeldriver has suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876933/can-i-write-an-alias-that-takes-an-argument#comment1363434_876933).

Answer (score 2):

> Then when I go to compile remotely

That's your main problem. The aliases defined in local config file or local interactive shell, won't work on remote system. Define the alias in your remote machine's `~/.bashrc` and it will work then.

A better approach would be to define a function, as Eliah suggested. But you would still have to define it on the remote machine, as with an alias.

Comment: I think you're right about this being the OP's problem. It hadn't occurred to me that this was the problem. The particular command the OP ran themselves, `g++ file.cpp -o file \`pkg-config --cflags opencv --libs opencv\``, would require a function rather than an alias. But if their original alias worked, then perhaps they don't need to pass the linker flags at the end after all. In that casem an alias will work fine, provided that it has really been defined in the shell in which it is run.