# How to make a command in ubuntu with choices and arguments

Tags: command-line, bashrc

So the question would be fairly short.

I would like to add options and arguments to alias created by us in .bashrc file it so how can I do it(cause almost everything is possible in computers) if it is possible

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://xyproblem.info/). Please narrow it down to what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and search for `getopts` in the `bash` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass arguments to an alias command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626458/can-i-pass-arguments-to-an-alias-command), [Can I write an alias that takes an argument?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876933/can-i-write-an-alias-that-takes-an-argument), or [Aliases - able to pass arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218630/aliases-able-to-pass-arguments) But as Murphy said, you'll likely want to **[edit]** this to say what you're trying to do. If we've put this question on hold, your edit will get it automatically considered for possible reopening.

Comment: I have got my answer at the first article which might get my answer. Thanks for linking there